# jsPDF not displaying image from image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

I'm using following function to download a div on button click as a pdf in my project.

```
function printDocument() {
    htmlToImage.toPng(document.getElementById('divToPrint'), { quality: 0.95 })
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
            const pdf = new jsPDF();
            const imgProps= pdf.getImageProperties(dataUrl);
            const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
            pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 0,pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
            pdf.save("download.pdf");
        });
}
```

Following is the table I'm downloading

```
 <table className={classes.cart}>
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>StockID</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                cartItems.map(item =>
                <tr>
                    <td>{item.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{item.product.sku}</td>
                    <td>{item.product.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.prices.price.value}</td>
                    <td>{item.prices.price.value*item.quantity}</td>
                </tr>
                               <tr>
        <th colSpan={'4'}>Cart Total</th>
        <td>{flatData.subtotal.value}</td>
    </tr> 
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

The data is passed from the backend to set in the table as above.But if I use image url to display in the table as

```
<td><img src={item.product.img_url}/></td>
```

the image is not displaying in the downloaded pdf.But if I use an image stored in my project folder it is displaying in the downloaded pdf.Please Help